# illeagal indirection error in iterator class

Tags: c++, iterator

Got this error messege on an attempt to return the data from an Item template under iterator class.
I don't understand why Im getting an error (C++)..

```
template<class E>
class Item {
    Item<E>* next;
    E data;
public:

    Item() :next(NULL) {}
    Item(const E& pdata) :next(NULL), data(pdata) {}

    void setNext(Item<E>& next) { this->next = next; }
    Item<E>& getNext() { return next; }
    void setData(const E pdata) { this->data = data; }
    E& getData() { return data; }
};
```

this is the iterator class:

```
 class Iterator {
    Item<T>* p;
public:
    Iterator(Item<T>* pt = NULL) :p(pt) {}
    Iterator& operator++(int) {
        p = p->getNext();
            return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() { return *(p->getData()); }
    friend class RoundList<T>;
};
```

they're both under a template class that called RoundList (template )

help...?

Comment: In which line does your error occur?

Comment: T& operator*() { return *(p->getData()); }

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I tested.

```
template <class E>
class Item {
    Item<E>* next;
    E data;
public:

    Item() :next(NULL) {}
    Item(const E& pdata) :next(NULL), data(pdata) {}

    void setNext(Item<E>& next) { this->next = next; }
    Item<E>& getNext() { return next; }
    void setData(const E pdata) { this->data = pdata; }
    E& getData() { return data; }
};

template <class T>
class Iterator {
    Item<T>* p;
public:
    Iterator(Item<T>* pt = NULL) :p(pt) {}
    Iterator& operator++(int) {
        p = p->getNext();
            return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() { return p->getData(); }
};

int main()
{
    Item<int>* test = new Item<int>();
    Iterator<int>* iterTest = new Iterator<int>(test);

    test->setData(2);
    cout << iterTest->operator*() << endl;
    cout << (test->getData() = 4) << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure how you want to use your `Iterator`, but I tried with a simple type, like `int` and it works. Anyway I change your `*(p->getData())` in `p->getData()` since in `getData` you are already returning a reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, Im not getting this error any more after changing this line.
I tried to return getData() by value and stick with the line as it is, but got the same error.. I wonder why..

it's an assignment from school, and since the defined the Item's data member Data as E, I assume it's supposed to work on simple types..

Comment: If you got the same error, it means that the problem is elsewhere.